# jQuery selector parentsUntil

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <td id="tdtmp" runat="server">
                <div id="divRef" class="divRef">
                    <asp:Literal ID="lblRef" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, refer %>" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    <asp:Label ID="reference" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="txtRef" Text='<%# Eval("Reference") %>' runat="server" />

                    <span id="spanDetails" class="spanDetails"><%=Resources.V_Tableaux.detail%></span>

                    <div id="divAddCart" class="divAddCart">
                        <img id="checkCart" width="30" height="30" src="Medias/Config/Valid.png" 
                             title="<%=Resources.V_Tableaux.AddToCart%>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="divImg" class="divImgTxt">
                    <img id="PathImage" runat="server"
                        src='<%# Eval("PathImage") %>'
                        alt="PathImage"
                        title="<%=Resources.V_Tableaux.TitleimgClickZoom%>"
                        align="left"
                        style="margin-right: 10px;" />
                    '<%# Eval("TexteImage")%>'
                </div>
                <div id="tdItemTemplate" class="tdItemTemplate" style="display:none">
                    <div class="divItemTemplate">
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, prix %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="prix" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Prix") %>' runat="server" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, hauteur %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Hauteur" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Hauteur") %>' runat="server" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, largeur %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Largeur" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Largeur") %>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="divItemTemplate1">
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, toile %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Type_de_Toile") %>' runat="server" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal5" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, peinture %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Type_Peinture")%>' runat="server" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal6" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, dateacq %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Acquisition") %>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="divItemArtiste">
                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal7" Text="<%$ Resources:V_Tableaux, peintre %>" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="txtLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Peintre")%>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>

> Blockquote
```

jQuery code:

```
 var ImgCart = $('.divAddCart').find('img');
  ImgCart.click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var idref = $(this).parentsUntil("tr");
       idref.css("background-color", "red"); //ok i see the bac color
       var vbref = idref.find("div> #reference").text(); //ok i get the reference value

       var vbH = idref.find("#Hauteur"); // From herre i cant get the text element ???
       var vbL = idref.find("#Largeur");
       var description = "Tableaux artiste: " + $.trim(vbH.text()) + "x" + vbL.text();
       var vbPrix = idref.find("#price");
       var Qte = 1;
       var PrixTotal = Qte * vbPrix.text();
       var sqlStr = Qte + "', '" + vbref + "', '" + description + "', '" + vbPrix.text() + "', '" + 

        });
```

How to get the value of vbH ?
I mean the selector "idref" point on "tdtmp" after parentsUntil. tr is member of table listview and is the top node after table - tbody.
can somebody help me to solve this point
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I imagine that template will be repeated on the page, I recommend you to use css classes to select elements. With your current HTML you will probably have repeated ids on your page, what is not valid and could lead to problems when selecting.

In any case, I belive you specific problem is that you're not using `ClientIDMode="Static"` for `Hauteur` and `Largeur`. But again, please move your ids to css classes.

For example

```
<asp:Label ID="Hauteur" CssClass="txtLabel Hauteur" Text='<%# Eval("Hauteur") %>' runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Largeur" CssClass="txtLabel Largeur" Text='<%# Eval("Largeur") %>' runat="server" />
```

And your selector would be

```
var vbH = idref.find(".Hauteur"); 
var vbL = idref.find(".Largeur");
```